# Why non-English string is recognized in view but not in helper in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9.2

Why this:

```
<%= foo("Русский") %>
```

works in view, but this:

```
foo("Русский")
```

doesn't work in helper ?

```
Error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ')'
```

File's encoding is UTF-8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to add this line (must be first line) in your helper file:

```
# coding: utf-8
```

Comment: Works like magic :) Thanks! Could you point to some documentation on this ?

Comment: Isn't it `encoding` instead of `coding`?

Comment: If Matz said 'coding', I will start using this form ;-)